# When can one pass a linear operator under the integral?

Tags: analysis

Specifically, one the webpage: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GreensFunction.html

It is written that 
$$
\int\mathcal{L}G(x,s)f(s)ds = \mathcal{L}\left(\int G(x,s)f(s)ds\right)
$$

where $G$ is a Green function. Why can the linear operator be pulled out of the integral?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Because when $x$ is fixed the integral is a limit of linear combinations of $G(x,s_i)$'s.

Comment: I think this answer is pretty misleading; one of the main issues that makes analysis hard is that limits and integrals frequently do **not** commute.

Comment: @user296602 You are right, or course, but clearly the necessary condition I have indicated is also sufficient in this case, by virtue of various assumptions that the OP has neglected  to mention.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on your answer?

Comment: @Quoka the problem with the answer is the interchanging limit with linear operators, which is only true if the operator is continuous.